# Best way to upgrade Windows from v. 10.0.14393

Tags: windows, updates

What's the best / quickest way to upgrade Windows from Version 10.0.14393 LTSC to a more recent one ?

Windows Update app says I'm up to date.

Thanks!

Comment: Download 1809 LTSC ISO, Mount IT, run setup.Exe and select Upgrade

Comment: @magicandre1981 why upgrade to 1809? why not directly 1909?

Comment: 1909 is no LTSC Version, newest LTSC is 1809

Comment: @magicandre1981 if I read this correctly: https://www.itechtics.com/download-windows-10-enterprise-iso/, LTSC 2019 would be the equivilent of 1909 which came out november this year, right?

Comment: No [LTSC 2019 is 1809](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/whats-new/ltsc/#the-long-term-servicing-channel-ltsc)

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and then select Save.

Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the re-installation process.  Use the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: Why download and not directly upgrade? Both do the same basically.

Comment: Download and directly normally works, but sometimes did not for me, so I posted the method above.

Comment: The media creation tool CANNOT be used since the author is using `Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSC`.  The author will have to download the `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC` ISO from the [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx).  However, that won't

Comment: The Media Creation Tool can only be used to download (Enterprise, Enterprise N,  Education, Education N, Professional, and Professional N) ISOs.  The 2019 LTSC ISO is indeed different compared to that of the Windows 10 Enterprise 1903 ISO.